# jpg not displayed by HTML img tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress, permissions

I'm trying to setup a wordpress website from a Raspberry Pi home server. The site works fine, except that I cannot display images (jpg). There is quite some info on the net concerning this problem. I typically boils down to:
(1) wrong path or (2) wrong permissions. 
My script reads the files, gets the EXIF, etc, so I guess path nor permissions are the issue. Still, I cannot display the images. 
The images are in a symlink.

```
$dir = getcwd ();
$cdir = scandir($dir);
foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) {

$info = getPermission($value);
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($value);
if ($value != ".." && $value != "."){

$num3 = $num3 . "width: " . $width . "<br />";
$num3 = $num3 . "height: " .  $height "<br />";
$num4 = $value . ": ". file_exists($value)." | ". $info." writeable: ".is_writable($value)."<br>";    
$num1 = $num1 .  '<img src="'.$value.'" width="100" height="50" />'.'<br>';
$exif = exif_read_data($value, 0, true);
foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
$num3 = $num3 . "$key.$name: $val<br />\n";
}
}
}      
}
echo $num1 . "<br>";
echo $num3 . "<br>";
echo $num4 . "<br>";

function getPermission($value){
$perms = fileperms($value);

switch ($perms & 0xF000) {
case 0xC000: // socket
$info = 's';
break;
case 0xA000: // symbolic link
$info = 'l';
break;
case 0x8000: // regular
$info = 'r';
break;
case 0x6000: // block special
$info = 'b';
break;
case 0x4000: // directory
$info = 'd';
break;
case 0x2000: // character special
$info = 'c';
break;
case 0x1000: // FIFO pipe
$info = 'p';
break;
default: // unknown
$info = 'u';
}

// Owner
$info .= (($perms & 0x0100) ? 'r' : '-');
$info .= (($perms & 0x0080) ? 'w' : '-');
$info .= (($perms & 0x0040) ? (($perms & 0x0800) ? 's' : 'x' ) : (($perms & 0x0800) ? 'S' : '-'));

// Group
$info .= (($perms & 0x0020) ? 'r' : '-');
$info .= (($perms & 0x0010) ? 'w' : '-');
$info .= (($perms & 0x0008) ? (($perms & 0x0400) ? 's' : 'x' ) : (($perms & 0x0400) ? 'S' : '-'));

// World
$info .= (($perms & 0x0004) ? 'r' : '-');
$info .= (($perms & 0x0002) ? 'w' : '-');
$info .= (($perms & 0x0001) ? (($perms & 0x0200) ? 't' : 'x' )   (($perms & 0x0200) ? 'T' : '-'));

return $info;
}
```

This is the output:

[the image shows what I can best describe as broken link: just the outline of the size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvCl8.png)

```
width: 600
height: 400
FILE.FileName: img_fjords.jpg
FILE.FileDateTime: 1514897050
FILE.FileSize: 37075
FILE.FileType: 2
FILE.MimeType: image/jpeg
FILE.SectionsFound:
COMPUTED.html: width="600" height="400"
COMPUTED.Height: 400
COMPUTED.Width: 600
COMPUTED.IsColor: 1

img_fjords.jpg: 1 | rrwxrwxrwx writeable: 1
```

Obviously, I can read the file, it is even writeable according to the permissions.

Thanks,

Dimitri

Comment: I think it's a typo, but you set `$num3`twice

Comment: Has to be accessible through browser too, try reaching it from browser with the name in $value.

Comment: is your image on a separate folder, if so you must add it to your src ($value)